# I have overwrited Win 7 OS by installing Hyper-V Server, how do I restore my PC to Win 7 again?

Tags: hyper-v

I was trying to install Hyper-V Server 2008 on my PC which already had installed Win 7 and what happend is that I have somehow overwrited Win 7 and now when I turn on my PC, Hyper-V Server 2008 starts to load and I can't do nothing about that!

Can anyone suggest me how can I redu this action so I could use my Win 7 OS again?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!

Adi

Answer (score 0):

Restore from backup is likely the only option that will work for you.  However, you can try booting the Windows 7 DVD and choosing the Repair option to see if it can recover.